# Apple Instruments: Where do <non-object> items come from?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

When checking memory allocations in Apple Instruments, I get thousands of "" items which all have "TextInput" as "Responsible Library".

I am not using the keyboard in my app.

Where do these objects come from?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<non-object>` means that it is an arbitrary hunk of `malloc()`ed memory.  It isn't an Objective-C or C++ object.

If there is only one, then don't worry about it.   It *might* be a real leak or it might be some tricky implementation detail that is hiding the reference from the leaks scanner.

Comment: I have thousands of these "non-object" items. All of them have  "Responsible Library" set to "TextInput" (according to Instruments). Do you have any idea where that might come from?

Comment: @AlexR  Ooh.. then that is bad.  No, I don't know what might be causing that.  As it potentially looks like a UIKit issue, I'd suggest filing a bug and posting the # here.